# Literature on Private Countries

Tags: political-theory, anarcho-capitalism

Amidst Anarchocapitalist authors such as Murray Rothbard, are there any who discuss the possibility of privately-owned countries?

Private countries would be shares of land owned by investors which would possess their own laws, courts, police and otherwise public services. Such enterprise's profit would come from rent.

Comment: In what way is it (privately owned countries) different than a "regular" country with its own set of laws (police, courts and all government institutions?)

Comment: Don't citizens privately own their country?

Comment: K Dog, do they? Can you sell your part of the country you're a citizen of?

Comment: Serfdom, Fiefdom, Feudalism, Colonialism, take your pick.

Comment: I would be kind of surprised if anarchists had anything nice to say about kings.

Comment: Given that definition, I would think of Belgian Congo or (nominally) feudal Japan, none of which were nice places to live unless you were on the top of the society. I think you should explain what you are talking about.

Comment: Question reworded for the sake of clarity

Comment: The common name for a private government is a monarchy or feudal regime. Company towns also have that character.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I could recommend a few writings, although the list is by no means extensive.

If you're interested in works by Anarcho-Capitalists in particular, one individual of interest is Hans-Hermann Hoppe. He is known for advocating for Monarchy as a more 'capitalist' form of government than Democracy. He also wrote on a variety of topics that would be of interest in relation to your question - Anarcho-Capitalist solutions to national defense, gated communities as a form of organization in an Anarcho-Capitalist society, etc.

If I remember correctly, he touches on these topics in the following works:

- *Democracy: The God That Failed*
- *The Economics and Ethics of Private Property*
- [*The Myth of National Defense. Essays on the Theory and History of Security Production*](https://mises.org/etexts/defensemyth.pdf)

Furthermore, Neoreactionary thought is largely based in the concept of privately owned countries or "sovereign corporations". These ideas were pioneered by the blogger Curtis Yarvin, under the pseudonym "Mencius Moldbug". A full collection of his works can be found [here](http://moldbuggery.blogspot.dk/). Of particular interest in this case are the following posts:

- A formalist manifesto
- Patchwork: a positive vision (part 1)
- Patchwork 2: profit strategies for our new corporate overlords
- Patchwork 3: what we have and what's so bad about it
- Patchwork 4: a reactionary theory of world peace

Finally, you might be interested in publications by groups such as the **Seasteading Institute**, which seeks to, among other things, address the practical and legal issues associated with running a settlement that is located outside the territory claimed by any government.